# PHP: do while with double OR condition

Tags: php, do-while

I would stop a while if `$sell` is GREATER than `$buy` **OR** `$k` is LESSER than 0.5

```
$high = 0.002420;
        $buy = 0.0024123;

        $k = 1;

        do {

            $sell = $buy + ( ( $buy * $k ) / 100 );

            echo '<p>'.$sell.' con k = '.$k.'</p>';

            $k = $k-0.1;

        } while ( ( $k >= 0.5 ) || ( $sell > $high ) );
```

In my example cycle need to stop after FIRST one iterate. Instead, it is executed when `$sell` is LESSER than `$high`, omitting firt condition (cannot go under 0.5 for k).

```
$sell is 0,002436423 con k = 1

$sell is 0,0024340107 con k = 0,9

$sell is 0,0024315984 con k = 0,8

$sell is 0,0024291861 con k = 0,7

$sell is 0,0024267738 con k = 0,6

$sell is 0,0024243615 con k = 0,5

$sell is 0,0024219492 con k = 0,4

$sell is 0,0024195369 con k = 0,3
```

Thank you

Comment: When you use a negation **OR** as a true statement, it shall be changed to **AND**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop when `$sell > $high`, then you want to *continue* when that is *not* true.

Also: stopping when *A or B* is true is equivalent to continuing when *(not A) and (not B)* is true.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning you have written "I would stop a while if $sell is GREATER than $buy OR $k is LESSER than 0.5" .. so you should compare $buy with $sell, and you have compared $sell with $high

try this:

```
while ( ( $k >= 0.5 ) and ( $sell <= $buy ) );
```